# How can I send data to a fragment when I click a button?

Tags: android, string, button, android-intent, fragment

I have MainActivity with some buttons and I have different class with array of strings. 
Can I send data (as I click on button) to a fragment so that it can choose from which class it takes the array strings?

Answer (score 0):

If you instantiate your fragment in MainActivity:

```
MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
```

Then you can call methods from that fragment inside MainActivity like: `fragment.myMethod(index_of_array);`

If you do your fragments in XML, then you should find it by id.